# PostgreSql : Not able to retrieve rows after inserting them into DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_post_items(i_data json)
 RETURNS table (fulfiller_id character varying,item_id character varying, order_id character varying, 
 status_id integer, 
-- sku_code character varying, decoration_technology character varying, quantity integer,  
 item_updated_time timestamp without time zone)

AS $function$
begin

 insert into vw_item_status_detail (fulfiller_id ,item_id ,order_id , status_id , sku_code ,
 decoration_technology ,quantity, item_updated_time)
 select 
    i_data->>'fulfillerId', 
    t->>'itemId', 
    i_data->>'orderId', 
    1000,
    t->>'skuCode',
    t->>'decorationTechnology',
    10,
    now()
  from json_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items') t
 returning fulfiller_id ,item_id ,order_id , status_id , item_updated_time;
 
-- returning fulfiller_id ,item_id ,order_id , status_id, item_updated_time;
 

end;
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Sample Data to run the stored function

```html
select * from post_items('{"orderId": "s",
 "fulfillerId":"kv0fdt6cx7",
"orderDetailsUrl":"het",
"items":[
    {
        "decorationTechnology":"laserEngraving","itemDescription":"Test Sku for Oracle testing",
"itemId":"aagasdsam1",
        "manufacturingUrl":"h-d9ccea00cn-prepress",
        "skuCode":"CIM-QYXB3789","productName":"Tsdacle testing","quantity":"225","taskId":"33a1sd769876c52"
    },
    {
         "decorationTechnology":"ssdas"
         "itemDescription":"Test Sku for satesting",
         "itemId":"aagam2",
         "manufacturingUrl":"httsadfa2d72-f225-4a03-addd-d9ccea00c874~1sadlpen-spress",
         "skuCode":"CXB3789",
         "productName":"Test Sku for Oracle testing",
         "quantity":"225",
         "taskId":"33asad6c52"
    }
]
}'::json)
```

When I try to run the function values are inserted into DB but in return nothing is recieved.

**Expected output**
To return params mentioned in the return query of the Stored function

Have tried a multiple ways but always get no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
...
returning fulfiller_id ,item_id ,order_id , status_id , item_updated_time;
RETURN NEXT;
RETURN;

...
```

From here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING

42.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY

> RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY do not actually return from the function — they simply append zero or more rows to the function's result set. Execution then continues with the next statement in the PL/pgSQL function. As successive RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY commands are executed, the result set is built up. A final RETURN, which should have no argument, causes control to exit the function (or you can just let control reach the end of the function).
> .

`RETURNS table` is an alias for `RETURNS setof` so you need to return a set by using `RETURN NEXT`.

**UPDATE**

My mistake. I thought I remembered that `RETURN NEXT` would automatically pick up the out variables. To make this work you will need to assign the values from `RETURNING` to the out(table) variables before the `RETURN NEXT`. As example:

```
\d names
                       Table "public.names"
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer                |           | not null | 
 name   | character varying(200) |           | not null | 
 animal | character varying(200) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "names_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.return_test(id_in integer, name_in character varying, animal_in character varying)
 RETURNS TABLE(id_out integer, name_out character varying, animal_out character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO
        names (id, name, animal)
    VALUES
        (id_in, name_in, animal_in)
    RETURNING id, name, animal INTO id_out, name_out, animal_out;

RETURN NEXT;
RETURN;
END;

$function$


select * from  return_test(1, 'ranger', 'dog');

 id_out | name_out | animal_out 
--------+----------+------------
      1 | ranger   | dog
(1 row)
```

Comment: So i need to append - RETURN NEXT;
RETURN;
-

Even after that I get no output

Comment: See **UPDATE**.

Comment: Also an FYI on name collisions. You may need to alias the table name in the `INSERT` and use the alias in the `RETURNING` clause. Otherwise you may get a duplicate name error with the column names for the `TABLE` output.