# How to return multiple inserted rows from a Stored function with insert select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Sample Problem with queries Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308286/postgresql-not-able-to-retrieve-rows-after-inserting-them-into-db/64308709#64308709)

Not able to get any inserted row in the RETURNING statement with INSERT and SELECT command even after adding RETURN NEXT; RETURN ;

**SCHEMA FOR USER TABLE**

> create table "user" (name text not null, updated_time TIMESTAMP NOT
> NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );

**function which needs to be updated to return inserted rows**

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFn()
    
    RETURNS table (name character varying , updated_time timestamp without time zone ) AS $$ DECLARE BEGIN
    
    insert into "user" (name , updated_time) 
    select 'alex',now() 
    union 
        select 'alex2',now() 
returning name, updated_time;
    END;
    
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function only inserts into DB but doesnt return the inserted rows with updated time on calling the function

it return no output on

> select * from testFn()

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name the link in the description has the complete code  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308286/postgresql-not-able-to-retrieve-rows-after-inserting-them-into-db/64308709#64308709)

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name tried to update the question properly with schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler to do with a `language sql` function. Try this (based on the previous version of your function):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_post_items(i_data json)
 RETURNS table (fulfiller_id text,item_id text, order_id text, status_id integer, item_updated_time timestamp)
AS $function$
 insert into vw_item_status_detail
 (fulfiller_id ,item_id ,order_id , status_id, sku_code, decoration_technology, quantity, item_updated_time)
 select 
    i_data->>'fulfillerId', 
    t->>'itemId', 
    i_data->>'orderId', 
    1000,
    t->>'skuCode',
    t->>'decorationTechnology',
    10,
    now()
  from json_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items') t
 returning fulfiller_id, item_id, order_id, status_id, item_updated_time;
$function$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

or for the updated function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFn() 
 RETURNS table (name text, updated_time timestamp without time zone ) AS
$$    
  insert into "user" (name , updated_time) 
    select 'alex',now() 
    union 
    select 'alex2',now() 
  returning name, updated_time;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: this doesn't returns anything

Comment: @AagamDoshi How did you invoke it? It returns 2 rows with 2 columns. Did you try `select * from testFn()`?

Comment: select * from testFn() @Stefanov.sm

Comment: Yes it works for the example !! I am not sure why its not working for my exact use case for sp_post_items, is it because in the example i am inserting into table and my exact usecase I am inserting into a View??  @Stefanov.sm

Comment: @AagamDoshi  I do not think that a view would make a difference. However I have not tried to see what would happen if the view has an `instead of insert` trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a `language sql` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFn()
  RETURNS table (name character varying , updated_time timestamp without time zone ) 
AS 
$$ 
  insert into "user" (name , updated_time) 
  values 
    ('alex', now()), 
    ('alex2', now())
  returning "user".name, "user".updated_time;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

With a `language plpgsql` you would need a `return query`, rather then just putting the insert into it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFn()
  RETURNS table (name character varying , updated_time timestamp without time zone ) 
AS 
$$ 
begin
  return query
    insert into "user" (name , updated_time) 
    values 
      ('alex', now()), 
      ('alex2', now())
  returning "user".name, "user".updated_time;
end;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To run the function use:

```
select *
from testfn();
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dea26cdbc29e5064f9b09bfbabea8886)

Comment: tried this, it doesn't return anything - I am using insert into select statement as the input needs to be extracted from json. Hope that might not be the cause of the issue

Comment: @AagamDoshi: yes it does: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dea26cdbc29e5064f9b09bfbabea8886